# read multiple values from one column mysql

Tags: php, mysql, string, hash

i have a Mysql database column like this

```
+----------------------------+
|PhoneNumber                 |
+----------------------------+
|0378617186#0381716116#      |
+----------------------------+
```

so i wanted to extract that single value into different values.. each phone number values separated by `hash (#)`.

I took it to the needs of my PHP login function.. some people has a phone number more than 1, so based on my problems... that person can login using first number (0378617186) or the second number (0381716116), so i need PHP to executing the `hash (#)` symbol into `OR` function.

any kinds of ur help would be helpful to me... 
thanks

Comment: This is terrible database design, so if you control the database schema, the real answer is to not store multiple values per column. If you don't control the schema, first chastise whoever does :-), then use something like $numbers = explode('#', $column) and loop through the resulting array.

Comment: It looks like you've just started working on the project, so changing things should be easy and better do it now than later. 
If it's possible, try changing the schema to something like this : `[userID][phoneNumber][user1][123456][user1][345566][user2][5677]...`.

Comment: Did you mean judging if a phone number is one of user's registered phone numbers by sql statement?

Comment: agreed.. this database schema worst.. but I was just told to do it based on that schemas :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really enforced to keep this database schema then you can use the following query that converts PhoneNumber column to up to 10 rows (you can adjust it accordingly, also change t1 table name to the table name you are currently use):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.PhoneNumber, '#', numbers.n), '#', -1) name
FROM (
    SELECT 1 n 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4
    UNION ALL SELECT 5
    UNION ALL SELECT 6
    UNION ALL SELECT 7
    UNION ALL SELECT 8
    UNION ALL SELECT 9
    UNION ALL SELECT 10
) numbers 
INNER JOIN t1
ON CHAR_LENGTH(t1.PhoneNumber) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(t1.PhoneNumber, '#', '')) >= numbers.n - 1
ORDER BY PhoneNumber, n;
```

Comment: perfecto!! that's what i need.. thank you my friend :D